# Error while persisting record

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

I am trying to persist a record in a remote database. But I am getting the following error:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.3.v20110304-r9073): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Configuration error.  Class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] not found.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.configurationErrorClassNotFound(DatabaseException.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.loadDriverClass(DefaultConnector.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getServerSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:209)
    at com.vistakon.util.Props.insertRowCount(Props.java:98)
.
.
.
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy135.onMessage(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.execute(MDListener.java:574)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.transactionalOnMessage(MDListener.java:477)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.onMessage(MDListener.java:379)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.onMessage(JMSSession.java:4659)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.execute(JMSSession.java:4345)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.executeMessage(JMSSession.java:3821)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.access$000(JMSSession.java:115)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession$UseForRunnable.run(JMSSession.java:5170)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
```

Here is my **persistence.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="prjEjbProj" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<!--        <jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/MSSQL1</jta-data-source> -->
        <class>com.model.DbLogTable</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:weblogic:sqlserver://mssql1.xxx.xxx.xxx.com:1433;databaseName=mydb" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="pwd" /> 
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My EJB module (a message driven bean) is deployed on a Weblogic server. I have hardly ever used JPA/EJB3/Weblogic. So may be I am making a basic error, but I am not able to find it out. From the error, the driver which I am specifying in persistence.xml is surely wrong, can anyone tell me what driver should I specify? Is there anything else I should change?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh damn..........I guess  `weblogic.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver` works.

Comment: Congrats on solving your problem.  When you are able to, please mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others can learn from your solution.  Cheers~

Comment: @Andrew: i can accept my own answer only after 2 days of posting it. but i will surely do so.